# Getting properties of ember component from ember component-class

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-components, ember-octane

I have been trying to get the value of a property of a component from action from its class. My main goal is to relate two objects: the "auction" passed into my component (shown in the code below)

**new.hbs**

```
<AuctionForm 
    @auction={{@model.auction}}
    @products={{@model.products}}/>
```

with the selected product on a select tag inside the "AuctionForm" Component as so:

**auction-form.hbs**

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="product">Produto</label>
    <select name="product" onchange={{action 'selectProduct' value='target.value'}}>
        <option value="" selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>-------</option>
        {{#each @products as |product|}}
            <option value="{{product.id}}" selected={{if (equalstr product.id @auction.product.id) 'selected'}}>{{product.name}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</div>
```

and I want to bind these two objects on the "selectProduct" action of the class:

**auction-form.js**

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { action } from '@ember/object';


export default class AuctionFormComponent extends Component {
    @action selectProduct(product) {
        this.get('auction').set('product', product); // this doesn't work on ember newest version
    }
    @action save(auction) {
        auction.save();
    }
}
```

Although, whenever I try to access its value on the component-class via "this.get()" function (just as I used to do on previous ember versions) I get an error saying that "this.get is not a function".

After digging a lot on the web I couldn't find a straightforward solution neither the official solution provided by the documentation.

The closest I got to a solution was to declare "auction" as a computed property (https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.22/classes/Component). But, I could not manage to implement it on a javascript file, once its structure (like the code below) only works on TypeScript files.

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { action } from '@ember/object';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';


export default class AuctionFormComponent extends Component {
    auction: computed('auction', function() {
        return this.auction;
    }
    @action selectProduct(product) {
        debugger;
        this.get('auction').set('product', product);
    }
    @action save(auction) {
        auction.save();
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows the correct way of performing such a task in ember 3.22?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using the modern Glimmer components (imported from `@glimmer/component`),

1. The arguments have to be accessed via the [`args` property](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/glimmer-components/#toc_arguments) inside the js class, like, `this.args.auction`.
2. The arguments (`auction` and `products`) are not mutable inside the component. To change the value of an argument, we can [send an action to the parent](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/glimmer-components/#toc_one-way-data-flow) to change the value.
3. The `get` and `set` methods are not available in glimmer components. Those methods are part of the classic ember component. You can access the properties of a class just using the dot [.] notation like: `this.auction` and reassign values using the assignment statement like `this.property = 'value'`
4. Since you are using native class syntax, `action: computed(..)` is not a valid declaration.
5. To bind events, it's recommended to use [`on` modifier and `fn` helper](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/action-on-and-fn/)

By combining all the points,

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class AuctionFormComponent extends Component {
    @action 
    selectProduct(event) {
        // This `updateProduct` has to be implemented in parent class 
        // which mutates the `auction` object.
        this.args.updateProduct(event.target.value); // -> `on` modifier will capture the native event
    }

    @action 
    save(auction) {
        auction.save();
    }
}
```

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="product">Produto</label>
    <select name="product" {{on "change" this.selectProduct}}>
        <option value="" selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>-------</option>
        {{#each @products as |product|}}
            <option value="{{product.id}}" selected={{if (equalstr product.id @auction.product.id) 'selected'}}>{{product.name}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</div>
```

and the invocation would be like,

```
<AuctionForm 
    @auction={{@model.auction}}
    @products={{@model.products}}
    @updateProduct={{this.updateProduct}}
/>
```

Here, `updateProduct` needs to be implemented properly to update the product.

---

**EDIT:** As @BPorto mentioned in a comment, this [Ember octane migration cheat sheet](https://ember-learn.github.io/ember-octane-vs-classic-cheat-sheet/) will be handy while migrating the codebase from classic ember model to Octane model.

Comment: Thank you very much for the elucidative answer, worked pretty well.

Comment: In case anyone is struggling to migrate from previous versions of ember to the new one (just like me), here is a link with some very helpful comparation between Ember and Ember Octane. Hope it helps! [link](https://ember-learn.github.io/ember-octane-vs-classic-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: The cheatsheet will be definitely useful. will add it to the answer itself.